# what is the equivalent of object in C# for objective C?

Tags: c#, objective-c, types, ambiguity

In c# I can declare `object o;` then I can assign `o=(float)5.0;` or `o="a string."` Is there an equivalent for Objective-C? I tried to use `id` but it does not take primitive type like float or integer. Thanks for helping.

Comment: `Can` doesn't mean `should`; the liberal use of objects can lead to run-time errors that perhaps could have been caught at compile-time using more specific types.

Comment: I am sure I am not the only person who need this. The reason is that I am developing a platform. I tried to do more work on my end so my customers will do less.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Objective-C doesn't have a "unified type system" in the words of the CLR. In other words, as a superset of C, Objective-C's primitive types are *different* beasts altogether than object instances. The `id` type can store references (really pointers in the OS X/iPhone Objective-C runtime) to any object instance. C's primitive types (e.g. `int`,`float`,etc.) must be wrapped in `NSValue` or `NSNumber` to be assigned to type `id`. Of course, this is exactly what the C# compiler is doing. It's just that in C#, you don't have to do the (un)boxing conversion explicitly.

Pretty soon, code like

```
float val;
id obj = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:val];
...
float v = [obj floatValue];
```

will become second nature, if unfortunately verbose by modern standards.

Comment: Thanks Barry. I ended up doing exactly what you suggested. Since I need to store a mix bag of c type data in an array, it there an easy way to detect the data type once it is converted into NSNumber?

Comment: `NSNumber` is a subclass of `NSValue`, so you can use `-objCType` and do C-string comparisons to determine the actual number type... pretty old school, but it works. This is a case where Objectie-C's desire to feel dynamically typed and C's static typing run afoul of each other.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't really such a thing.  You can use `NSNumber` or `NSValue` to handle native data types as objects.  `NSString` will do strings.  You can assign all of those to an `id` typed variable, but you'll need to create them with the correct class's `init` methods.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, `id` only works for ObjC object references. If you want to reference an int with an id reference, you need to box it into an `NSNumber`. Incidentally, C# is boxing those primitives too, it's just doing it automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Back in my day we had to walk 15 miles in the snow, uphill, to use [void pointers](http://theoryx5.uwinnipeg.ca/programming/node87.html). Oh, and we didn't have StackOverflow!

Comment: I like this, but I have to -1 because doesn't answer the question. ( try making CW and I'll upvote it  then )

Comment: +1 because the World is a better place with some humour in it.

Comment: In my mind void * is actually the closest thing to a base type such as 'object' in c#. You _could_ use it to reference an arbitrary value, but I wouldn't seriously suggest that. Therefore, my answer is not serious.

Comment: Also, I think it's a great thing that we're at a point where a unified type system is generally considered to be a good thing. Java blew it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, C# data types are just aliases for their respective classes and that's why they can be assigned to object type.
For example, int is actually a class called Int32.

As @Barry mentioned earlier, that's not the case with Objective-C.